# How do I add Floor mouldings with Archipack Pro in Blender 2.8?

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

I am using a July 22nd build of Blender 2.8 beta. I am using Archipack Pro. I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKH5scLVlC0 but it looks like it's an older version because mine looks very different.

I have selected the walls, but I cannot find the create curves-> Mouldings panel.

This is how their screen looks:
[image]

This is how mine looks:
[image]

I might be overlooking something obvious, but the documentation is not the greatest and some of it is out of date now or just nonspecific enough it's difficult to figure out what needs to be done first. https://blender-archipack.gitlab.io/user/archipack%20objects.html?highlight=molding This is where the documentation mentions it, also with something called "slab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there.

For automatic flooring and molding etc. you need to click on the Archipack tab and then on the wrench. All that with your walls selected of course.

[image]

More generally speaking Stephen hangs out on BlenderArtist if you have questions. I agree that the documentation and the tutorials are lacking in general principles.