# Tutorial on Wall Borders?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, workflow

There are no tutorials anywhere on how to build Wall Borders, I have a picture here that I posted, I hope someone can help and guide me through the process on how to make this on Blender 2.8.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and where, *specifically*,  are you stuck?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/how-do-i-add-floor-mouldings-with-archipack-pro-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical way would be simply to duplicate the bottom edge of the wall, and convert it to a curve, down which you can sweep a profile of the molding.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Duplicate the bottom edge of the wall
- <kbd>P</kbd> separate it into its own object, and Header > Object Menu > Convert it to a curve. (The 'Path'). Make the path a 2D curve, to ensure clean miters.
- Construct a profile for the molding, either as a mesh which you convert to a curve, or as a curve in the first place. (The 'Profile')

[image]

Note the orientation of the profile curve with respect to its object axes, and the position of its origin at its bottom left corner (shown with the 3D Cursor). All this can be adjusted in Edit Mode.

- Now just assign the 'Profile' curve as the Bevel Object of the 'Path' curve.

[image]

You might want to convert the 'Path' curve back to a mesh when you're done, to make Auto Smooth available for it. That way, you can keep the poly count down.

Comment: .. but as @Duarte points out, if you have to do a lot of this, Archipack would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Start by drawing the profile of the moulding.  The profile is what it looks like from the cut end.  Fill the profile with one of more faces, then extrude that face in the direction you want.  UV map it and you are off to the races.