# How do I extend edges until intersection to create a corner from two perpendicular faces?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am recreating a building for a project but I don't know how to extend the edges of the buttress to create a corner. On the real building the top of the corner is the same vertex as the tops of the two sides.

For the bottom each side has one vertex and shares one vertex.

Here is an image of what I am referring to.
[image: The blue pencil is a wire drawing of what I'm trying to achieve.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hesitate to post this one, it's peculiar to right-angle corners..

[image]

- <kbd>V</kbd> on the common edge, to ensure faces are separated
- Select the faces, and *Bridge Edge Loops* with the settings as shown.

The 'Smoothness' setting will stick, making repeats a bit quicker.

But a more general method would be to create the buttresses already mitred, either by [putting a profile down a 2D curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158991/35559), or by..

[image]

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Extruding a face-loop along normals, with 'Offset Even' checked
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Lowering the top edge

Answer (score 2):

As your walls are aligned with the global X and Y axis, what you can do is use the *Snap* option. First enable the *Snap to Vertex* option (you'll use Ctrl to snap) and also the *Auto Merge* option:

[image]

Then remove the faces, move the first edge on X or Y, depending, press Ctrl so that it snaps to the other edge, move the second edge until it snaps and merges with the first one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great way to do it, but one thing you might try is just manually copying the coordinates. select one of the points and in the n panel on the right, copy down the relevant coordinate (X in this case):

[image: part1]

Then after you paste it into the x position to your other vertex, you can use merge (m) to make just one vertex at the new position:
[image: part2]

Repeat for both vertices on the edge and you should be good.

Comment: This definitely isn't a great way to do it... Why not use the snapping functionality at least?..